# How to implement isRePin() function

Tags: pinterest

I'm using the Pinterest API to fetch pins from a specific board, and I want to know which Pins created by the board owner and which pins are Re Pins. For some reason I couldn't find how to do that via the API.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Add the 'creator' to the 'fields' in the request. It will return the first and last name, ID, and profile URL of the pin's creator. The ID would be interesting to compare with the ID of your board owner. I am not sure if the creator ever changes, but it is worth looking into.